# How or where to download the openjfx gradle plugin binaries?

Tags: gradle-plugin, openjfx

I am a Gradle beginner. I have to download the binaries of org.openjfx:javafxplugin:0.1.0 whose source code is available at @https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin in order to use this plugin offline.

https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin and https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.openjfx.javafxplugin only provide sources, not binaries.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-plugin provides downloadable outdated binaries releases up to 0.0.13 and latest binaries releases located  on an EEA SK repository but the latters are unreachable.

And I only found snapshots on Nexus repository @ [https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick~javafx](https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick%7Ejavafx).

I tried building a empty maven project using this plugin as a dependency to retrieve it in the .m2 local maven cache but it didn't work.

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>fr</groupId>
  <artifactId>cl</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>download_javafxplugin</name>
  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Where can I found this plugin binaries without rebuilding from sources or how can I download automatically this plugin in a cache using Maven or Gradle ?

Comment: The Gradle plugin portal is a Maven repository. You can see all the versions of `org.openjfx:javafx-plugin` here: https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/openjfx/javafx-plugin/. But note that the JavaFX plugin has [transitive dependencies](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin/blob/master/build.gradle#L20) which may themselves have transitive dependencies. If you can, I recommend running your Gradle build _once_ online, then you can use `--offline` thereafter. It will be easier that way.

Comment: Thank you very much @Slaw. Your answer solved my problem. The single dependency, 'com.google.gradle:osdetector-gradle-plugin:1.7.3', doesn't have a runtime dependency itself. I prefer to avoid building online as I have to build on my personal computer and copy the artifacts to my offline pro desktop and it is not recommended by my organization for security reasons.